# RPATH failed to expanding

Tags: macos, dyld, rpath

I have built an executable (named demux) on OS X that always fails to load and I cannot find why:

```
$ ./demux
RPATH failed to expanding     @rpath/sfeMovie.framework/Versions/2.0/sfeMovie to: @executable_path/sfeMovie.framework/Versions/2.0/sfeMovie
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/sfeMovie.framework/Versions/2.0/sfeMovie
  Referenced from: …current_dir/./demux
```

The framework is next to the executable. Otool shows the following :

```
$ otool -L sfeMovie.framework/Versions/2.0/sfeMovie 
sfeMovie.framework/Versions/2.0/sfeMovie:
@rpath/sfeMovie.framework/Versions/2.0/sfeMovie (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 2.0.0)
```

And:

```
$ otool -L demux 
demux:
@rpath/sfeMovie.framework/Versions/2.0/sfeMovie (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 2.0.0)
```

Given that, I thought that adding @executable_path to the runtime search path of the executable would allow it to look at any framework and library whose relative install name is simply prefixed with @rpath (like in @rpath/sfeMovie.framework/…) and which is next to the executable. To make sure that this runtime search path is correct:

```
$ otool -l demux | grep LC_RPATH -A 2
      cmd LC_RPATH
  cmdsize 32
     path @executable_path (offset 12)
```

But this fails and I don't know why. To me @executable_path/sfeMovie.framework/Versions/2.0/sfeMovie looks like the correct path but it still fails… is there any misuse of @rpath or @executable_path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue with a quick test project. It was fixed when I appended a trailing slash to the `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATH` build setting.

Instead of:

```
@executable_path
```

you should try

```
@executable_path/
```

The output from `otool -l` now looks like this:

```
      cmd LC_RPATH
  cmdsize 32
     path @executable_path/ (offset 12)
```

In general, you can check your toplevel executable (in this case "demux") with my dyld analyzer script at https://github.com/liyanage/macosx-shell-scripts/blob/master/checklibs.py

```
./checklibs.py demux
```

This tool attempts to faithfully reproduce `dyld`'s resolution logic. It can usually provide a hint about which references don't work, but in this case it doesn't catch the issue with the missing trailing slash. I will update it accordingly to match `dyld`'s behavior.

Comment: Oh that was it!!! Thank you so much!! It does more looks like a dyld bug as it prints a valid expansion path but fails to load… anyway, solved :) Will have a look at your script too :)

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. I agree, this behavior does not match the documentation.

Comment: It looks like `@executable_path` (without "/") works well on 10.9 El Capitan, although I can confirm that on 10.7 Mavericks you have to use `@exectuable_path/` (I have app compiled to 10.7 target working on 10.9 but not on 10.7 - after spending few hours finding issue I found out that the "/" was the problem...) Thanks @marc-liyanage!

Answer (score 0):

`demux` contains an `@rpath` link, and RPATH contains `@executable_path`, but the [dyld man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html) says, “You can even add a `LC_RPATH` load  command  path  that starts  with  `@loader_path`” which seems to imply that `@executable_path` isn’t allowed in RPATH.

If `demux` contains `@executable_path` directly instead of indirecting to `RPATH`, then it will work.

See [man dyld](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html)  and [dyld.cpp](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-239.3/src/dyld.cpp) for the gory details.

If this is `demux.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo();

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", foo());
}
```

and this is `lib/sfeMovie.c`:

```
int foo() {
    return 42;
}
```

and this is your `Makefile`:

```
run:
        $(MAKE) clean
        $(MAKE) demux
        cd .. && "$(shell pwd -P)/demux"

demux: demux.o lib/sfeMovie.dylib
        cc -o $@ $^
        install_name_tool \
            -change \
                'lib/sfeMovie.dylib' \
                 '@executable_path/lib/sfeMovie.dylib' \
            $@

lib/sfeMovie.dylib: lib/sfeMovie.o
        cc -shared -o $@ $<

clean::
        rm -f demux *.o lib/*.o lib/*.dylib
```

Then `demux` loads the library correctly, even if the current directory is not the one containing `demux`. However if `sfeMovie` is referencing a bunch of other libraries then you may still need an RPATH.

Comment: With your scheme, the user is forced to put the library in a lib directory next to the executable. And if he does not want that he'll have to edit the dylib before linking against it (or edit the executable after every link step). I forgot to give a precision about this point: I want to let he user choose where to put the framework, which is why I'm trying to use rpath. Thanks though :)